# Uploading multiple files using html5 and php

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a file upload form set up with the HTML5 multiple attribute.

However, the form still only uploads a single file. Do i need to create some sort of a looping function in the php or is there another way of doing this?

Here's my code...

form:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
       <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file[]" id="file" />
       <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />    
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {           
foreach($_FILES['newsImage'] as $file){ 
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {


    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: post your form code also. it should contain a multi-part specification.

Comment: Your code seems to be processing only one file - are you sure the problem is on the *upload* side of things?

Comment: It is worth noting that IE (and Opera I think) does not support choosing multiple files through the `<input type="file" />` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['newsImage']['name']); $i++) {
    // handle upload
}
```

Comment: Why did you accept your own answer which was answered two weeks after mine (which is the same solution ... ?) Seems a bit weird I have to admit (:

Comment: The foreach won't work due to the structure of the file array when using a multiple file input. You need to define each file info part as $_FILES['inputName']['name'][0] for the first filename, $_FILES['inputName']['name'][1] for the second, etc.

Comment: Although this is an old post, I've come across this issue as well. Indeed, uploading multiple files does make the array structure more complicated, thus using a regular for loop like this one really helps. I'm sure there is a way to use foreach, but this is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your field should be 
`<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" />`

And then in PHP:

```php
<?php
   foreach($_FILES['files'] as $file){
       // Handle one of the uploads
   }
?>
```

Comment: I've amended my code based on your reply, it doesn't seem to upload anything now though... any ideas... thanks

Comment: Inside your loop you are still calling `$_FILES['file']['type']` etc... you should call `$file['type']` (the specific file inside the loop over your files array).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this code could serve the purpose.
It loops through the `$_FILES` array and creates an array with **`key => value`** pair of all the attributes for for each file.

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($_FILES['file'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $index => $val){
        $temp[$index][$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php   

    include 'db.php';

      extract($_POST);

        extract($_POST);
        if(isset($submit))
        {

          $count = count($_FILES['image']['name']);

           for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
           {
              $fname = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
              $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
              $file_size =  $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
               $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'][$i];
               echo $file_size,$file_type;         
               $target = "img/".$fname;
               move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$target);
                echo "uploaded succ !"."<br>";

           }

        }

?>
```